# render json on the client in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created file uploading component in react which is going to upload csv file and parse it and render it as json on the client. But now my code can upload csv file on the console log only, and I have a hard time why it didn't parse csv and render it on the browser (client side).

I looked into react tutorial video but still can't figure out how can I parse and render csv as json output on the client. how can I make this happen? any hack to get this done? any thoughts? Thanks

**my file component**:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';

export default class FileUpload extends Component {
//   constructor(props) {
//     super(props);
//   }
  // how to post those to database
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      fileUpload_status: 'false'
    }
  };
  handleFiles = files => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
    // Use reader.result
    var csv = reader.result;
    var lines = csv.split("\n");
    var result = [];
    var headers=lines[0].split(",");
    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");
      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }
      result.push(obj);
      }  
      result= JSON.stringify(result, null, 4); //JSON
    console.log(result);
  }
  reader.readAsText(files[0]);
  // format json as standard json object
}
  render() {
    return (
      <ReactFileReader handleFiles={this.handleFiles} fileTypes={'.csv'}>
        <button className='btn'>Upload</button>
        <div>{console.log(this.props)}</div>
      </ReactFileReader>
    );
  }
}
```

I got this issue because whenever csv file is uploaded, I want to populate this data to cloud database. I couldn't solve this problem. Can react community helps me out with my issue? is there any hack to fix the issue? any solution?

**goal:**

I am expecting local csv file to be parsed as json and render the content on the browser (client). how can I achieve my goal? any solution to get this done? thanks

Comment: "render json on the server" = huh? Sounds like you want to do this on the client.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane sorry for confusion, yes, I want to render it on the client, I am new to react though. could you help me how to get over this problem? any idea? thank you

Comment: You are probably not forming your output properly. You can paste in in here to see where: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane I  did that and I got this error when I validate that `Expecting 'EOF', got ','`. Plus, input for file upload component comes from google form, I want to upload it to client side as json. Could you give a possible hack to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: seems to work here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eh7rz1

Comment: @JuniusL. thanks, but I want to parse uploaded csv as json on the client. can you elaborate your answer based on this requirement?

Comment: you want to display the data as raw json?

Comment: @JuniusL. yeah but I want to get rid of timestamp which should not be included in the parsed output and should not be displayed as well. thanks for your help and looking forward to seeing your further extend the solution. please post your solution as an answer so I could accept your community contribution.

Comment: @JuniusL. I updated my post with the expected json output format that supposed to be rendered on the client side (browser). any update on your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) and `JSON.stringify()`

```
 this.setState({
    data: JSON.stringify(result, null, 4),
  });
```

Render your JSON string

```
 <pre>{this.state.data}</pre>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eh7rz1?file=FileUpload.js)

Comment: please provide me with sample csv

Comment: here is the example csv file that I am going to upload and parse it as `json`: [google form file](https://jmp.sh/v/xnXsbLmQw06hUH4DtEAb). Please let me know if link doesn't work for you.

Comment: I updated my post with the expected json output format that supposed to be rendered on the client side. Could you update your solution? thank you

Comment: @woody I've updated the demo, seems to be working as expected.